# could not upload any thing other than jpg

Tags: php, zend-framework, image-uploading

i this code for uploading in my zf application :

```
public function uploadAction() {
    $upload = new Zend_File_Transfer_Adapter_Http();
    $upload->setDestination("uploads");
    if (!$upload->isValid()) {
        throw new Zend_Exception("Upload Error");
    }
    try {
        $upload->receive();
    } catch (Zend_File_Transfer_Exception $e) {
        throw new Zend_Exception('Upload Error ' . $e->getMessage());
    }


    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
}
```

and following html :

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="admin/upload" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="Filedata" type="file" /><br />
<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='10000' />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

everything works fine with jpg files ... but i got zend exception on JPG and png and ... etc :

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Exception' with message 'Upload Error' in D:\xampp\htdocs\sc\application\controllers\AdminController.php on line 2539
>   ( ! ) Zend_Exception: Upload Error in D:\xampp\htdocs\sc\application\controllers\AdminController.php on line 2539

i debugged the exception and var dump validator message  ... found this :

```
array


'fileUploadErrorFormSize' => string 'File 'Filedata' exceeds the defined form size' (length=45)
```

Comment: `File 'Filedata' exceeds the defined form size` Check your php.ini for max_post_size, max_upload_filesize and max_file_uploads: http://de.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size

Answer (score 1):

You only need one `<input type='hidden' name='MAX_FILE_SIZE' value='10000' />` statement. 10000 is a little small, as that means you're limited to a 10Kb file...

Comment: lol ... fixed by adding uploading to AUTO on uploadify script